# How do I return a Python bottle template that prints out key-value pairs from a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, html-table, bottle

The purpose is to extract data from a dictionary and return the key-value pairs in the form of a table
This is the section of my Python code:

```
dictionary = dict()
dictionary = {'hello': 1, 'hi': 2, 'go': 3}
output = template('make_table', wordList=dictionary)
return output
```

This is part of my make_table.tpl file:

```
<table>
%for index in wordList:
    <tr>
        <td>{{index}} </td>
    </tr>
%end
</table>
```

Unfortunately the tpl file only diplays the keys: 'hello', 'hi' and 'go', but not their values.

What I want is to be able to able to display:

> hello 1 hi 2 go 3

Can anybody tell me how I index values as well on the tpl file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can iterate over the dict items in the template using `iteritems()`:

```
<table>
%for key, value in wordList.iteritems():
    <tr>
        <td>{{key}} </td>
        <td>{{value}} </td>
    </tr>
%end
</table>
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bottle import template
>>> t = """
... <table>
... %for key, value in wordList.iteritems():
...     <tr>
...         <td>{{key}} </td>
...         <td>{{value}} </td>
...     </tr>
... %end
... </table>
... """
>>> print template(t, wordList={'hello': 1, 'hi': 2, 'go': 3})
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>go </td>
        <td>3 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hi </td>
        <td>2 </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>hello </td>
        <td>1 </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```